# directory is shown as file on windows

Tags: android, windows, file, directory, explorer

After using the following code i get a perfectly working folder. At least when i check it with my android file explorer.

As soon as i try to open the folder on windows i can only see a file called "test".

[image]

The code:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test");
folder.mkdir();
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{folder.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

I also added the following permission to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also i already added the read permission in case the media scanner needs it. This didn't work either.

I noticed that this code works perfectly fine on Android 4.4.4 but creates the said file on 5.1.1.

I would be very happy if anybody had an answer to that. I have been searching for an answer for some time already.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'As soon as i try to open the folder on windows i can only see a file called "test".' So if you open the folder 'test' on windows you see a file 'test'? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: @greenapps instead of the folder i get a file with the exactly same name (without any extension).

Comment: What are you doing exactly?

Comment: I edited the question and added an image. I simply want to create a folder, that's it.

Comment: `As soon as i try to open the folder on windows` AND `What are you doing exactly`. You did not tell what you exactly are doing in windows. Place a few more directories in that folder. Make them with a file explorer on your device. Then tell what you all see or post new pictures.

Comment: It can't be that complicated: i want to create a folder but in windows this folder appears as a file

Comment: Sunch uninformative comments don't bring you any further. Better do as i requested. You are not even reacting.

Comment: What i am doing exactly in Windows: open explorer -> navigate to mobile phone -> double click on internal storage -> here should be a folder named "test" but there is the file called "test" (see image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Android:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37055810

Even commercial Apps suffer this problem. If I understand it correctly even the pre-installed Apps on some devices!

Android versions from 4.x to 6.x seem to have this problem.

According to some forum entries there is no real solution for this. The only work-around I have found was:

- delete the app private data of a certain Android-internal app
- download another special app from the appstore which ...
- ... does nothing but triggering the first app to re-build its private data

> code works perfectly fine on Android 4.4.4

My device runs 4.4.4 but it shows the problem!

So not all devices having the same Android version behave the same way.